# Code not filtering data under specified conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to manipulate some data based on some observations existing in a variable

I have the following code:

```
beg.new1     <-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,0,0)
 dive_type1<-c('stocked',   'stocked',  'stocked',  'stocked',   
'stocked',  'stocked',  'stocked',  'stocked')

dt<-data.frame(beg.new1, dive_type1)

dt%>%
 mutate_all(as.character)%>%
  mutate(beg.new1=case_when(beg.new1 %in% c('3','4') & dive_type1=="Pre- 
stocking" |dive_type1=="Prestocking" ~ '3', 
                               beg.new1 %in% c('0', '1', '2')~ '0',
                               TRUE~as.character(beg.new1)))
```

I expect this to return no data as 'Pre-stocking' and 'Prestocking' are not observed in the data on this occasion. I am trying to filter the data so that beg.new1 '3' is only returned under dive_type 'Prestocking' etc. However, R is returning beg.new1 '3' under 'stocked'! Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rephrase this as:

```
dt %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate(
    beg.new1 = case_when(
      beg.new1 %in% c('3','4') & dive_type1 %in% c("Pre-stocking", "Prestocking")  ~ '3',
      beg.new1 %in% c('0', '1', '2') | (beg.new1 %in% c('3', '4') & dive_type1 == "stocked") ~ '0',
      TRUE ~ beg.new1
      )
    )
```

Output:

```
  beg.new1 dive_type1
1        0    stocked
2        0    stocked
3        0    stocked
4        0    stocked
5        0    stocked
6        0    stocked
7        0    stocked
8        0    stocked
```

The problem is that you haven't specified what happens in case `dive_type1` equals `stocked` and you have something higher than 2 in the first column; this was therefore handled with `TRUE`, i.e. the original value was kept.

Comment: Ok, if stocked it should just return '0' beg.new1 which is what your rephrased code does...  Could I just remove the TRUE statement? Thankyou

Comment: In this case you could - but if your data frame contains other examples and you'd like to keep their values, you'd need to keep it. You're welcome! Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.